# Where are sound settings?

Tags: sound, microphone, settings

I'm trying to use a different microphone.  Everything I find tells me to go to sound settings but I can't find them.  Under settings I can only find About, Date & time, Users and Default Applications.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On ubuntu Desktop 19.10, you should be able to change microphone input by going to the "settings" menu found by doing the following:

1. From the desktop either press your super key (normally the windows button) or click "activities" in the top left corner of the screen.
2. type "sound" and press enter
3. A settings window should now appear showing sound settings. One of
   the headings on this screen is labeled "Input" (you may need to
   scroll to see it). From there you should see a dropdown of all audio inputs.

[image]

It should also be possible to bring up the settings screen using the terminal:

```
gnome-control-center
```

and then you should see sound listed on the left hand menu.